# 18.04 gcc a simple c program

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

appear

```
functionTest01.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory  #include <stdio.h>
```

when i see friends suggestion。sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
appear

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu11) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.23-0ubuntu11)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: IMHO I think this question is more appropriate for the Ubuntu forum: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: You have added another source in your system which is providing updated libc6 package while for libc6-dev to work, downgraded version of libc6 is required. Fix your sources or downgrade libc6  package manually.

Comment: i am in china.because firewall，i just can use our coutry source. I prepare compile source package of gcc and gdb.but there is lot of denpency package such as gmp and  mpc so on.